# Laravel 8 default RegisterController. Pass parameters in array

Tags: laravel-8

I'm trying to create a form for register a user with a Vue component.
I want to use the default routes generated by Auth::routes(); and the default "create" function by the default RegisterController from Laravel 8

This is the create() function I see on RegisterController but it doesn't seem the function that the route is calling.

```
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

But this is the created route:

```
|POST| register| generated::RuTERdEs1GA9zWNu | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register| web
```

Why do I have a create() function if the route points to "register"? What's the function this "register" is actually calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `register` method is actually part of the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;` trait. This is where the validation is called, the user is created, the `Registered` event is fired and the user is logged in.

It was set up this way to abstract so that the bits your most likely to change are easily available but the other parts of the code which are more essentially/less likely to need updating aren't "cluttering" your controller.